# Как добавить в TextView версию API того устройства, на котором запускается приложение?

Tags: java, android, api, textview

Как добавить в TextView версию API того устройства, на котором запускается приложение? 
Проблема в том, что версия API становится известна только в момент установки приложения на устройства, в связи с этим я не представляю, как добавить данные об API в TextView

Comment: textView.setText( ""+android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);

Comment: @Style-7, огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте android.os.Build.VERSION.

> CODENAME: текущее кодовое название разработки.
>
> INCREMENTAL: внутреннее значение, используемое базовым источником
>   контроля для представления этой сборки.
>
> RELEASE: видимая пользователем строка версии.

Пример

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) { 
// only for gingerbread and newer versions 
}
```

Comment: Премного благодарен!